# I found these in my bathroom and WC

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Are they somehow dangerous? What are they and how can I get rid of them?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are silver fish (*Lepisma saccharina*) and harmless. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silverfish) says (image taken from the article):

> Silverfish are nocturnal insects typically 13–25 mm (0.5–1.0 in)
>   long. Their abdomens taper at the end, giving them a fish-like
>   appearance. The newly hatched are whitish, but develop a greyish
>   hue and metallic shine as they get older. They have two long cerci
>   and one terminal filament at the tips of their abdomens; the filament
>   projects directly off of the end of their body, between the left and
>   right cerci. They also have two small compound eyes, despite other
>   members of Zygentoma being completely eyeless, such as the family
>   Nicoletiidae.
>
> Like other species in Apterygota, silverfish are completely
>   wingless. They have long antennae, and move in a wiggling motion
>   that resembles the movement of a fish. This, coupled with their
>   appearance and silvery scales, inspires their common name. Silverfish
>   typically live for two to eight years. Silverfish are agile runners
>   and can outrun most of their predators (including wandering spiders
>   and centipedes). However, such running is possible only on horizontal
>   surfaces, as they lack any additional appendages, and therefore are
>   not fast enough to climb walls at the same speed.[citation needed]
>   They also avoid light.

[image]

Comment: disgusting. They look like cockroaches with their antennas.....